# Less latency when scrolling with ctrl-e and ctrl-y

Tags: scrolling

Is there a way to scroll faster using Ctrl-e and Ctrl-y?

When I hold down Ctrl+e for example, it scrolls one line of text but then **pauses for about half a second** before scrolling the rest of the text.

Is there a way to get rid of that pause / reduce that latency? I might not have been looking in the right place, but I couldn't find anything in the help docs

NOTE: I'm **not** asking for how to scroll multiple lines at a time.

Comment: Please expand the question wit information about OS, terminal or GUI, which terminal. Is it reproducible with `vim --clean`? I can't reproduce it (Linux, GNOME terminal & GUI).

Comment: Does the behavior change after you do `:set timeoutlen=50`?

Comment: @Ralf I am able to reproduce the issue using `vim --clean`. It's strange that you're not able to reproduce the issue. I see the same behavior on `vim 8.1` on Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04, WSL, and my raspberry pi. I'm using the terminal version of vim not the GUI gvim

Comment: And `:set timeoutlen=50` and other values of `timeoutlen` didn't change anything